# Asending order for hiredate

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

What am I doing wrong?

```
SQL> select ename, job, oder by (ascending order)hiredate  from emp where hiredate between '20-FEB-81' AND '01-MAY-81';
select ename, job, oder by (ascending order)hiredate  from emp where hiredate between '20-FEB-81' AND '01-MAY-81'
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected


SQL>
```

Table

```
SQL> select ename, job, hiredate  from emp where hiredate between '20-FEB-81' AND '01 MAY-81';

ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE
---------- --------- ---------
BLAKE      MANAGER   01-MAY-81
JONES      MANAGER   02-APR-81
ALLEN      SALESMAN  20-FEB-81
WARD       SALESMAN  22-FEB-81

SQL>
```

Comment: See your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373117/asending-order-for-hiredate and read the sql syntax and note order of commands

Comment: You are asking too many questions which are simple syntax errors.  The Oracle documentation is comprehensive, online and free.  Please read it before posting any more such questions.  Find it here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

order comes last (you also had "oder" not "order")

```
select ename, job, hiredate  
from emp where hiredate between '20-FEB-81' AND '01-MAY-81'
order by hiredate  asc
```

ascending is the default so unless you want descending it is not needed but it is good for readability

Answer (score 2):

1. The `ORDER BY` clause comes after the `WHERE` clause
2. The `ORDER BY` clause is a separate clause-- you don't apply it to the column in the `SELECT` list.
3. The syntax is `ORDER BY column_name [ASC|DESC]`

So you'd want something like

```
SQL> select ename, job, hiredate
  2    from emp
  3   where hiredate between to_date( '20-FEB-81', 'DD-MON-RR' ) and
  4                          to_date( '01-MAY-81', 'DD-MON-RR' )
  5   order by hiredate asc;

ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE
---------- --------- ----------
ALLEN      SALESMAN  1981-02-20
WARD       SALESMAN  1981-02-22
JONES      MANAGER   1981-04-02
BLAKE      MANAGER   1981-05-01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ename, job, hiredate  from emp where hiredate between '20-FEB-81' AND '01 MAY-81' order by hiredate acs
```